# Paying taxes as a freelancer and as a formal employee in the US

Tags: usa, visa, working-visas, tn-visa

Currently I am working in the US under a TN visa and in 2019 I did some freelancing projects (4 in total) were I got paid (1 in cash and the rest with checks). I am doing my taxes this year and I don’t know how should I put this extra income under my taxing for the IRS. I haven’t gone with any accounting person yet because it’s been quite difficult since I have had to travel and I just got notified that my W2 form has arrived. Please, any help or guidance about my situation will be very valuable for me.

Comment: My tax preparer lets me send her my paperwork. She asks me questions by e-mail if she needs to clarify anything or thinks there should be another statement. You may want to look for a preparer who can work that way.

Answer (score 1):

So far, this is what I found: https://www.freelancetaxation.com/the-minimum-freelancers-need-to-earn-in-order-to-have-to-file-income-taxes

Answer (score 1):

If you've been doing US taxes as an employee for years and doing your own taxes, you might be able to read up about the extra form to include your freelance business income (Schedule C) and do it yourself. But if you haven't been doing your own taxes, and have been seeing a tax preparer or accountant, this probably isn't the time to start doing it yourself.

If you go to a tax preparer, be sure to bring information about any expenses you incurred while conducting your freelance business, such as driving, insurance, permits, supplies, etc.

Comment: I did my taxes with available software in 2017 and 2018. Last year was the first time I got some extra income.

Comment: I file Schedule C each year. I haven't checked yet for tax year 2019, but in the past I had to buy a "home and business" version of the tax software because the free versions wouldn't do Schedule C. It cost around $60; shop around, some retailers are more expensive than others.